# How do I split \nameref text across two rows, within a single table column?

Tags: tables, formatting, nameref

I have the following table

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[a4paper,layout=a4paper,
        bindingoffset=4cm,left=0cm,right=2cm,
        head=2.5cm, bmargin=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{microtype}            
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage{multirow} 
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, shapes, chains, fit, backgrounds, calc, decorations.pathreplacing, matrix, calligraphy, positioning}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[inline, shortlabels]{enumitem} 
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}    

% try and get a lower case first letter for the section hyperlinks working
\newcommand{\lnameref}[1]{%
\bgroup
\let\nmu\MakeLowercase
\nameref{#1}\egroup}
\newcommand{\fnameref}[1]{%
\bgroup
\def\nmu{\let\nmu\MakeLowercase}%
\nameref{#1}\egroup}
\newcommand{\nmu}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{threeparttable}
\tabcolsep=0.1cm
\begin{tabular}{l | l | l | l | l}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{\nameref{ssec:Sx}} & \multirow{2}{*}{Age-group} & Partnership & Usual resident & Hours worked in \\
    & & status & in household\tnote{1} & employment per week\\
    \midrule 
    \addlinespace
    Male & 0-4 years & \nameref{ssec:Prtnrd} & One usual resident & 1-9 hours \\ 
    Female & 5-9 years & Non-partnered & Two usual residents & 10-19 hours \\
    & 10-14 years & NEI\tnote{2} & Three usual residents & 20-29 hours \\ 
    & 15-17 years & & Four usual residents & 30-39 hours \\ 
    & 18-24 years & & Five usual residents & 40-49 hours \\
    & 25-34 years & & Six usual residents & 50 hours or more \\ 
    & 35-44 years & & Seven usual residents & Not working\\ 
    & 45-54 years & & Eight or More & NEI\tnote{3} \\ 
    & 55-64 years & & & \\ 
    & 65-74 years & & & \\ 
    & 85 Years \& Over & & & \\
          
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
    \footnotesize
    \item[1] The count of individuals in the household was collected on the separate Dwellings Form, but the information on each individual was collected on the Individual Form.
    \item[2] An aggregate of the residual categories. These categories included ``response unidentifiable", ``not stated", and ``refused to answer". All children in the age groups 0-4 years, 5-9 years, and 10-14 years were coded to this personal relationship category by Stats NZ.
    \item[3] An aggregate of the residual categories. These categories included ``Don't know", ``Refused to answer", ``Response unidentifiable", ``Response outside scope", and ``Not stated". Non-response was coded to ``Not stated" unless the respondent clearly indicated they refused to answer the question. All children in the age groups 0-4 years, 5-9 years, and 10-14 years were coded to ``Not working" by Stats NZ.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\caption{Population data variables and their values.}
\label{tab:PopData}
\end{table}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\subsubsection{\nmu Sex}\label{ssec:Sx}
Sex is the distinction between males and females based on the biological differences in sexual characteristics.
In responding to a question on sex, most people are able to classify themselves as either male or female. A person who has undergone sex reassignment is classified to that sex. A person who was of indeterminate sex and who has undergone sex assignment is classified to the assigned sex. Someone who is currently undergoing such procedures and living as the sex that they are taking steps towards is classified as that sex.

\subsubsection{\nmu Hours worked in employment} \label{ssec:Hwie}
Hours worked in employment is the total number of hours usually worked in employment each week by a person aged 15 years and over who:
\begin{itemize}
\item worked one hour or more for pay, profit, or payment in kind, in a job, business, farm, or professional practice, or
\item worked one hour or more without pay in work that contributed directly to the operation of a business, farm, or professional practice operated by a relative, or
\item had a job or business they were temporarily absent from.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

That produces this table
[image: Image of table produced by table code]

As you can see from the code and image, I'm splitting the column heading for the final column between two rows due to the length of the test. What I would like to do is to use `\nameref` to refer to the definition that I have labelled. The reason is that the reader will be able to move straight to the definition upon clicking the link, rather than having to scroll. This is part of a much longer document - my dissertation - so there are, in reality, pages between the table and the associated definition.

How can I get `\nameref{ssec:Hwie}` to replace the title of that final column, and have the text wrap between the two lines? As you can see, I have the hyperlink in place for "Sex", now I just need it for "Hours worked in employment".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `varwidth` to set a box with some maximum width, which you can guess at after looking at the result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  layout=a4paper,
  bindingoffset=4cm, % <---- really?
  left=0cm,
  right=2cm,
  head=2.5cm,
  bmargin=2cm
]{geometry} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcommand{\vp}[2]{%
  \begin{varwidth}{#1}\raggedright #2\end{varwidth}%
}

% try and get a lower case first letter for the section hyperlinks working
\newcommand{\lnameref}[1]{%
  \bgroup
  \let\nmu\MakeLowercase
  \nameref{#1}%
  \egroup
}
\newcommand{\fnameref}[1]{%
  \bgroup
  \def\nmu{\let\nmu\MakeLowercase}%
  \nameref{#1}\egroup
}
\newcommand{\nmu}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l l l l l @{}}
\toprule
\nameref{ssec:Sx} &
Age group &
\vp{6em}{\raggedright Partnership status} &
\vp{8em}{\raggedright Usual resident in household\tnote{1}} &
\vp{8em}{\raggedright \nameref{ssec:Hwie}} \\
\midrule 
\addlinespace
Male   & 0--4 years & \nameref{ssec:Prtnrd} & One usual resident & 1--9 hours \\ 
Female & 5--9 years & Non-partnered & Two usual residents & 10--19 hours \\
       & 10--14 years & NEI\tnote{2} & Three usual residents & 20--29 hours \\ 
       & 15--17 years & & Four usual residents & 30--39 hours \\ 
       & 18--24 years & & Five usual residents & 40--49 hours \\
       & 25--34 years & & Six usual residents & 50 hours or more \\ 
       & 35--44 years & & Seven usual residents & Not working\\ 
       & 45--54 years & & Eight or More & NEI\tnote{3} \\ 
       & 55--64 years & & & \\ 
       & 65--74 years & & & \\ 
       & 85 Years \& Over & & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
  \item[1] The count of individuals in the household was collected on the 
           separate Dwellings Form, but the information on each individual
           was collected on the Individual Form.
  \item[2] An aggregate of the residual categories. These categories included
           ``response unidentifiable'', ``not stated'', and ``refused to answer''.
           All children in the age groups 0--4 years, 5--9 years, and 10--14 years
           were coded to this personal relationship category by Stats NZ.
  \item[3] An aggregate of the residual categories. These categories included
           ``Don't know'', ``Refused to answer'', ``Response unidentifiable'',
           ``Response outside scope'', and ``Not stated''. Non-response was coded
           to ``Not stated'' unless the respondent clearly indicated they refused
           to answer the question. All children in the age groups 0--4 years,
           5--9 years, and 10--14 years were coded to ``Not working'' by Stats NZ.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\caption{Population data variables and their values.}
\label{tab:PopData}
\end{table}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore 
eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt 
in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\subsubsection{\nmu Sex}\label{ssec:Sx}
Sex is the distinction between males and females based on the biological 
differences in sexual characteristics. In responding to a question on sex, 
most people are able to classify themselves as either male or female. 
A person who has undergone sex reassignment is classified to that sex. 
A person who was of indeterminate sex and who has undergone sex assignment 
is classified to the assigned sex. Someone who is currently undergoing such 
procedures and living as the sex that they are taking steps towards is 
classified as that sex.

\subsubsection{\nmu Hours worked in employment} \label{ssec:Hwie}
Hours worked in employment is the total number of hours usually worked in 
employment each week by a person aged 15 years and over who:
\begin{itemize}
\item worked one hour or more for pay, profit, or payment in kind, in a job,
      business, farm, or professional practice, or
\item worked one hour or more without pay in work that contributed directly
      to the operation of a business, farm, or professional practice operated 
      by a relative, or
\item had a job or business they were temporarily absent from.
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Whatever}\label{ssec:Prtnrd}

\end{document}
```

I only left the necessary packages for the code at hand.

Note that number ranges should use an en-dash rather than a hyphen; I wouldn't use a hyphen in “Age group”.

Also `"` should be `''` for closing quotes. And, of course, vertical rules are bad. I added `\centering` inside `table` and `\bottomrule`.

[image]

Comment: The format is for my dissertation, so yeah, the offset is set for me.

Comment: @Michelle It's *very* large.

Comment: I know. :( I will double-check and see if they've changed it. Your answer worked perfectly, thank you! Now I have a whole bunch of dashes to turn into en-dashes...

Comment: :( "Pages may be printed on one or both sides, provided legibility is ensured. For doctoral examination, double line spacing is recommended for text, and the final copy may have 1.5 or double line spacing. Masterate students should follow the recommendations of their particular College. Margins should be at least 4 cm on the inner side (to allow for the binding), 2.5 cm at top and bottom and 2 cm on the outer side. Font size should be neither too large nor too small. A size of 10 - 12 point is recommended."

Comment: @Michelle I'd probably use `bindingoffset=2cm` and `left=2cm`

Comment: This is the specification: \usepackage[a4paper,layout=a4paper,
            bindingoffset=4cm,left=0cm,right=2cm,
            head=2.5cm, bmargin=2cm]{geometry}      %get the page layout right